# bootstrap carousel iphone5c

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, carousel

I'm using bootstrap to make a web site. On the browse everything is ok, but on the mobile(Iphone 5c) the carousel grows and shrinks. I tryed to fix the size of the carousel on many sizes like 320px, 480px, etc and add .img-responsive class.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` inside of the `<head>` tag in your html?

You need to do the pevious to ensure proper zooming on mobile devices.

[Source](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile)